# Alinhar paginação do Bootstrap na direita

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estou com um projeto que foi desenvolvido na versão Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.4. Nesse projeto tem uma paginação que segue os padrões do framework.

```
<nav aria-label="Navegação de página exemplo">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Anterior</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Próximo</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

O problema está no alinhamento, pois quando uso o dessa forma:

```
<nav aria-label="Navegação de página exemplo">
  <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">
    <li class="page-item disabled">
      <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Anterior</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="#">Próximo</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Não funciona... porém se eu retirar:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

E colocar:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Funciona, porém caga o layout todo :(

Já tentei usar o `pull-right` e o `text-right`, mas de nada adiantou.

Infelizmente é a manutenção de um projeto pronto e com isso não posso mudar a estrutura atual. Como posso alinhar a paginação para o lado direito sem impactar no layout?

Comment: Vc já tentou colocar na mão `.pagination {
            justify-content: flex-end !important;
        }` o Bootstrap tem uma hierarquia forte de classes e as vezes é necessário usar o `important`

Comment: Show de bola Hugo. Implementei no seu código `display: flex;` e funcionou. Obrigado!

Comment: Legal Fox.11 que bom que deu certo! Deixei a resposta mais completa caso vc queira aceita-la e não deixar a sua pergunta em aberto como Não Respondida sendo que já chegamos a uma solução. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente parece que vc está usando uma versão mais simples do Bootstrap que deve ter deixado de fora algumas *classes* dos `Utilities` como as classes de `Flex`. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/

Ou então devido a alguma hierarquia de classes tem alguma outra propriedade de `flex` substituindo a sua.

De qualquer forma vc pode usar esse CSS abaixo que vai resolver seu problema:

```css
.pagination {
    justify-content: flex-end !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<nav aria-label="Navegação de página exemplo">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item disabled">
        <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Anterior</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
        <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="#">Próximo</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Perfeito Hugo. Obrigado ;)

Comment: Valeu @Fox.11 tmj!